Can hardcoded passwords and tokens in a GCP Cloud Function be compromised?
How secure are hardcoded passwords and tokens in a GCP Cloud Function which has allowed public unauthenticated access?
I am very limited with time and I have no time to implement a secret manager's use in a Cloud Function. I wonder if this fairly safe to hardcode confidential data within Cloud Function. The Cloud Function is created manually and no data is pushed to GitHub.
I am concerned here mainly with the security outside of the small organisation. I am not worried about a small group of developers seeing that data at least not for now. That could be an issue in the future when the organisation grows. Could this data be leaked into the outside world?

usually the source code of a cloud function is available for those who can see that cloud functions (in console fro example)... in addition, if the source code is stored somewhere (in git of any implementation), it may be another weak point. Thus, in my personal opition, I would avoid such approach.

What do you mean by "safe"?  What exactly is your security concern?  We don't know who all has access to your project, who should or should not see these passwords, and we don't know what permissions they have that might give them that access.  Security is hard and can't be boiled down to a simple "safe" or "unsafe" proposition.  You need to decide what your security requirement are up front.  Please edit the question to elaborate.

Great point Doug Stevenson. I updated my question. Please let me know if this is clearer.

What do you mean by "exposed to the public"?  The security of a function, from an outside public perspective, depends entirely on what it actually does and how it gets accessed, which we can't see.  Without source code, we have no way of knowing for sure.

sorry, I updated my question, I meant public unauthenticated access

I assume this gives access only to API, so the only way for exposure of hardcoded values would have to be a bad source code that returns such values?

For what it's worth, implementing Secret Manager is very quick. Probably takes about as long as typing a Stackoverflow question.

It stands to reason with only these two assumptions:

Your only concern is potential abuse coming from direct access to some HTTP API endpoint
Your endpoint doesn't ever, under any circumstance, transmit sensitive data to the caller

Then there is no way that public access to that API endpoint could reveal any such sensitive data.  In that respect only, the sensitive data would be considered "safe".
Unless of the code actually does do that in some situation, but without seeing source code, we'll never know for sure.  Or, you start considering other vectors for abuse that don't involve invoking the public API endpoint.  A full discussion of possible attack vectors is well beyond the scope of an answer on Stack Overflow, and possibly alarm you given there are things attackers can do that you'd never think of.  As such, 100% security is extremely hard to ensure.
